# SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Express

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using xp. I want to learn SQL.

I have `SQL Server Management Studio Express`.

I dont know how it works but when I open it ,it says couldn't connect to server.
It asks for server name and instance name, I don't have any idea where to find server name and instance name.

Also looked for solutions related to server name and instance name but dont find SQL manager. Please tell me how to practice SQL?

I am Learning for the first time.Please help me.

Comment: Do you have only Management Studio? Or actual server? Have you tried putting `localhost` as server name and select Windows Authentication for login?

Comment: You need to start studying from the `installation` step.

Comment: You can't "learn SQL" with just Management Studio. You need [SQL Server Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/database.aspx)

Comment: I'll tell you one thing. Your question title is a name of a `Software`!! Does it sound like a question to you? Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There is something you shouldn't do to start with, jep it is in your first sentence...

Answer (score 1):

Hope [these videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAB997187BD64BB11) will help you to make first steps in studiyng SQL Server.

If you want to study just SQL (not specially SQL Server), you may like lessons on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

Comment: I would be a little careful about w3schools are they have a few items on there that are outdated or incorrect.